# Continuity of the divergence of a static electric field

Tags: continuity, physics

Let $\rho:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R$ be a continuous charge density function.  Define the electric field $\vec E:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ by $$\vec E(\vec r)=k\cdot\int_{\Bbb R^3}\rho(\vec{r}')\cdot\frac{\vec r-\vec r'}{\left|\vec r - \vec r'\right|^3}\,dV(\vec r'),$$ where $V$ is the volume measure and $k$ a positive constant.
Does it follow that $$\operatorname{div}\vec E=D_1E^1+D_2E^2+D_3E^3$$ is continuous?  If so, why?

Comment: Doesn't Gauss's law show that $\text{div}\vec{E}$ is continuous if $\rho$ is continuous?

Comment: @kobe Gauss' law says that $\int_{\partial B}\langle\vec E,n\rangle\,dA=k\cdot 4\pi\int_B\rho\,dV$.  How do you get continuity of $\operatorname{div}E$ from this?

Comment: That's the integral form. The differential form says $\text{div}\vec{E} = \rho/\epsilon_0$.

Comment: @kobe Yes.  But I was trying to prove the "differential" form by using the divergence theorem and the integral form.  In fact, we have that $\int_B(\operatorname{div}\vec E-k\cdot4\pi\rho)\,dV=0$.  If the integrand is continuous, then we can derive, being $B$ arbitrary, that $\operatorname{div}\vec E = k\cdot 4\pi\rho$. Otherwise, how do you get to the "differential" form?